# Return Inorder Traversal list

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree, inorder

I'm trying to return list from inorder traversal and below is my code. If my input is [1,2,3] and output should be [3,1,2], but I'm returning value none. Can you please suggest what is wrong in my code? Thanks.

```
def inorderTraversal(currentNode,output=None):

    if output==None:
        output=[]
    if currentNode.left:
        return inorderTraversal(currentNode.left,output)

    return output.append(currentNode.data)

    if currentNode.right:
        return inorderTraversal(currentNode.right,output)
```

Comment: BTW, `if currentNode.right:` will never be executed because it follows an unconditional `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
return output.append(currentNode.data)
```

You are returning the value of `append` but that is `None`. `append` changes the list but it does not return the new value of the list. Do this instead.

```
output.append(currentNode.data)
return output
```